# Putting a value in DynamoDB table with attributes as set of objects

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I need to persist an attribute in DynamoDB Table, whhere attribute is `Set<Some Class>`.

Basically I need to put that attribute in `Map<String,AttributeValue>`.
For generation situation we generally do

```
Map<String,AttributeValue> itemsInTable = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
        itemsInTable.put("Id", new AttributeValue("123"));
```

Now suppose I have a `Set<Info>` where `Info` is a class.

How to put that kind of Attribuute?

and also if the attribute Value is a list ??

Comment: is Set<Info> the value of a Map entry?

Comment: I didn't get you..?  Info is a normal java class.

Answer (score 1):

After two three days of research I just found there is no **direct** way to put something like `set<Info>` in DynamoDB using this kind of Notation.

```
Map<String,AttributeValue> itemsInTable = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
        itemsInTable.put("Id", new AttributeValue("123"));
```

But we can opt some middle way to convert the `Object` to  `JSONObject` or `JSONString` and put in `Map<String,AttributeValue>` by using

```
 Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
 Map<String,AttributeValue> itemsInTable = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
 itemsInTable.put("Id", new AttributeValue().withSS(set));
```

To convert object to jsonString we can take help of `jackson` library.

import this:

```
import zaaa.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObbjectMapper
```

Define `ObjectMapper`

```
private final ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

Now suppose class is `Container` and its corresponding Object is `container'

Now the main job is to convert it into `jsonString` which can be easily done by using `writevalueAsString` function.

```
String jsonString = jacksonObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(container)
```

Now we have jsonString, we can easily convert it to `JSONObject` or `JSONArray` whenever needed.

I solved my issue by using this way.